# How can I remove the duplicated consecutive chars and reserve the first one using regex?

Tags: python, regex, string

I found a code snippet of removing duplicated consecutive characters and reserving the first character in Python by regex from web like this:

```
import re
re.sub(r'(?s)(.)(?=.*\1)','','aabbcc')  #'abc'
```

But there is a defect that if the string is 'aabbccaabb' it will ignore the first 'aa', 'bb' and turn out 'cab'.

```
re.sub(r'(?s)(.)(?=.*\1)','','aabbccaabb')  #'cab'
```

Is there a way to solve it by regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `.*` in the positive look ahead.

```
import re

print re.sub(r'(?s)(.)(?=\1)','','aabbcc')
print re.sub(r'(?s)(.)(?=\1)','','aabbccaabb')
```

Output:

```
abc
abcab
```

Comment: or: `re.sub(r'(?s)(.)\1', r'\1', 'aabbccaabb')`

Comment: @ScottCarpenter It will work only for 2 repeating characters. Won't work for more than 2.

Comment: Still have a small question.If I got '\\' in my string,such as s = 'aa\\\\aa\\', how can I implement this,or I need to consider an exceptional occasion?

Comment: @ScottCarpenter `re.sub(r'(.)\1+', r'\1', 'aaabbccaabb')` This will work.

Comment: @Harrison Should repeating backslashes be replaced by 1 or none?

Comment: My bad, the code is right.I forget to print the result of re.sub.

Comment: @MYGz Question only mentioned duplicated, not triplicated or more. ;-) However your answer and suggestion are better for what's intended!

Answer (score 4):

Without regex, check if previous character is the same as current, using a list comprehension with a condition and join the results:

```
s='aabbccaabb'
print("".join([c for i,c in enumerate(s) if i==0 or s[i-1]!=c]))
```

Comment: Pretty Pythonic method.Thx.

Comment: On a similar note: `z=list(s); t="".join([u for u,v in zip(z,['']+z)if u!=v])`. That avoids the double test in the loop at the expense of converting the string to a list, and creating the second list, although most of that work is done at C speed, so it's pretty fast. We can avoid the conversion to list with `t="".join([u for u,v in zip(s,'\0'+s)if u!=v])` if we know `s` will never start with a NUL char, but I guess that's a bit kludgy. ;)

Comment: @PM2Ring I always forget that shifted zip thing. Thanks. Will keep that in mind.

Comment: there was also `s[0]+"".join([c for i,c in enumerate(s[1:]) if s[i]!=c])`

Comment: @PM2Ring `uvloop` nice :)